# How can a Spring Boot web app validate a form field that is required conditional on another field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, bean-validation

I have a Spring Boot web app in which fields of my form-backing bean are annotated with [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) annotations (see [Baeldung's tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation) or [the docs at spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-validation)).  For example, fields on Customer beans might be annotated like this:

```
@NotBlank
@Pattern(regexp="[ \\.A-Za-z-]*")
private String firstName;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern="M/d/yyyy")
@NotNull
@Past
private Date DOB;
```

What I want to know is: **(How) Can I implement a complex validation that looks at multiple fields?** I mean, using this framework.  For example, let's say I have a field `Country` and a field `ZipCode` and I want the `ZipCode` to be `@NotBlank` if and only if the `Country` equals `"US"`, optional otherwise.

In my Controller, the validation is very elegantly triggered with the  use of the `@Valid` annotation, and errors are attached to a `BindingResult` object.  Like so:

```
@PostMapping("customer/{id}")
public String updateCustomer( @PathVariable("id") Integer id,
                              @Valid @ModelAttribute("form") CustomerForm form, 
                              BindingResult bindingResult ) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "customerview";
    }
    customerService.updateCustomer(form);
    return "redirect:/customer/"+id;
}
```

What I'm hoping to find is a way to write this conditional validator in a way that it, too, will be triggered by the `@Valid` annotation and will attach it's error message to the `ZipCode` field in the `BindingResult`.  Ideally I shouldn't have to change the Controller code at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can getting help of creating custom validator class, the following link helps you:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator#custom-validation

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of stuff you need to use cross field validation. Please try :

Create annotation :

```
package foo.bar;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomerValidator.class})
public @interface CustomerValid {

    String message() default "{foo.bar.CustomerValid.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Create custom validator :

```
public class CustomerValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomerValid, Customer> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomerValid constraint) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Customer customer, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !("US".equals(customer.getCountry() && "".equals(customer.getZipCode())));
    }
}
```

Annotate your class :

```
@CustomerValid
public class Customer {
// body
}
```

This class validation will be processed in addition to existent field validators.